# React open select file dialog using ref not working?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, use-ref

I'm trying to open file dialog using react useRef hook.

when browser executes fileInputRef.current.click() code snippet I'm getting below error in console

error: File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 5):

This works well:

```
const inputFileRef = useRef();
...
const handleBtnClick = () => {
   inputFileRef.current.click();
}
...
<form>
  <input type="file" ref={inputFileRef} />
  <button onClick={handleBtnClick}>Select file</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @demkovych for speed response not sure what went wrong with my code but somehow it started working

Comment: It gives this error if you are calling `click` by stepping over it in DevTools. That is, if you had a breakpoint. Once you remove the breakpoint, it will work.